# How to split and find last index in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need to achieve something like following in Google-sheets:

```
tag_name    
A_B_C       C
A_B_C_D     D
```

I am using following formaula:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(B2, "__"), 0, 3)
```

I want to dynamically pass last index of the set of values returned by split.

Comment: [this link](https://www.extendoffice.com/excel/formulas/excel-get-last-word.html) might help.

Comment: Does split() exist in Excel? If not don't tag Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try **REGEXEXTRACT** formula, I am assuming your data range starts from "A1". Put this formula in "A1" and fill it down per your requirement

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\S$")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

for arrayformula try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A; "_(.)$")))
```

[image]

Comment: This returns the first index of underscore

Comment: @Odys https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfQ2f.png

Comment: You are right, it seems to be only working for single letter codes as OP requested, it doesn't work for words.

Comment: @Odys for words you can change `(.)` to `(.+)`